# Cocoa Custom Notification Example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

Can someone please show me an example of a Cocoa Obj-C object, with a custom notification, how to fire it, subscribe to it, and handle it?

Comment: Vague question.  Try asking a more specific question, or search Apple's documentation.

Comment: I wouldn't normally comment on a question like this, but seeing as how you received a "con" then mine can be a "pro". This question allows for a *concise* answer dealing strictly with the topic. I merely want to find out one simple thing - not *scour* apple's documentation (which would most likely be worth-while anyway). So thanks for asking this question. I see your +15 atm on the question being congruent with my sentiment.

Comment: Here is a app that i wrote, it might help you https://github.com/kylelk/Notification-example/tree/master

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
@implementation MyObject

// Posts a MyNotification message whenever called
- (void)notify {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
}

// Prints a message whenever a MyNotification is received
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)note {
  NSLog(@"Got notified: %@", note);
}

@end

// somewhere else
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
// receive MyNotification events from any object
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:object selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
// create a notification
[object notify];
```

For more information, see the documentation for [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-2831).

Comment: What's the point of using notification then? Why not just call [object handleNotification] straight?

Comment: Loose coupling. Note the "// somewhere else" comment... The notification is a kind of broadcast message. Any object instance can listen to a notification and doesn't need to conform to any particular delegate protocol or similar. There may be many instances listening to a single message. The sender doesn't need to have pointers to the object instance(s) it wishes to notify.

Answer (score 45):

**Step 1:**

```
//register to listen for event    
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(eventHandler:)
  name:@"eventType"
  object:nil ];

//event handler when event occurs
-(void)eventHandler: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"event triggered");
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
//trigger event
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"eventType"
    object:nil ];
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to unregister notification (observer) when your object is deallocated. Apple documentation states: "Before an object that is observing notifications is deallocated, it must tell the notification center to stop sending it notifications".

For Local Notifications the next code is applicable:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

And for observers of distributed notifications:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```