# iPhone / Objective C - Communication between ViewController / best way to implement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, viewcontroller

I'm doing a iPhone app.

I created my own SwitchViewController Class (linked to the App-Delegate) which actually just
changes the various other Views / ViewControllers (e.g ViewA, ViewB) while the app is running.

When I know recieve a tap-gesture in the ViewController-A I would like to trigger a method (eg. switchViews:(id)sender) in the SwitchViewController Class.

What would the best way to do this?
Must I initiate ViewA with a object-reference to SwitchViewController?
Delegate? What would be the best way?

When I add a button to ViewA its no problem, then I just can connect it to the IBOutlet. But programmatically?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used actually the responder chain, and recieved the tap in the switchViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a prime example for using the [NSNotificationCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778386/what-is-nsnotification-center-why-is-it-used-iphone-sdk/3778496).