# Inform Class(A), when Class(B) delegate methods complete execution using Notification in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I have written custom delegate methods in ClassFile(B), now i am calling them from ClassFile(A), now i want to notify Class(A) when class(B) delegate methods complete its execution.

How can i do in Objective C (in Iphone SDK) ??

A working sample example will be more appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use notification, selectors, blocks, or simply store a pointer to Class A in Class B.  Here is a notification example:

[Cocoa Custom Notification Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842737/cocoa-notification-example)