# Capturing one image after processing another on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to implement some image processing on iPhone. The program should work as following:

1. User touches a button to start the task;
2. Take one image from my AVCaptureConnection, process it, do something on camera configuration (like setting the point of interest, letting it refocus then lock the focus) based the processing result;
3. Take another image, process it;
4. Depending on the processing result above, go to (3) immediately or wait a few millisecond;
5. Repeat (3) and (4) until user stops it.

The problem I have in this task is that I don't know how to force these tasks to be run sequentially (taking the next step only after the last one is finished). I can only find the

```
captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection()
```

method to capture an image, which seems to run in the same thread in where it is called. As a result, I cannot call

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sometime]
```

to wait then check if the processing is completed without "sleeping" the processing as well.

Is there something else I can do to achieve the task, or do I have to use explicit threading myself?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using notifications, and it works nicely. I post a notification at the end of the handle invoked in captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(), so that when the code finishes processing, it calls in the next step through the notification center.

Here are [examples on custom notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842737/cocoa-custom-notification-example) and I basically followed it.